# How to reduce the width of v-switch

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The v-switch seems to always take 100% width, as seen below. Is there a way to reduce its clickable area to the minimum? Thanks!

[image]
clickable v-switch in the blank: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/switches/#usage

Answer (score 1):

You can add `d-inline-block` class to `v-switch` which will reduce the div width to the content's max width.

The alternative, as the previous answer explained, is to wrap it in a row/column. Either don't set a column value or set it to a number because `col-auto` may cause it to be more narrow than desired and cause label to go over multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read [this link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#usage) from **vuetify** documentation. the reason that **v-switch** is continuing to the right of page is that **v-container** above it. you can modify the layout with **vuetify grid system** like below:

> a Vue js page

```html
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <v-container
      class="px-0"
      fluid
    >

      <v-row>
        <v-col md="4">
          <v-switch
            class="my-border"
            v-model="switch1"
            :label="`Switch 1: ${switch1.toString()}`"
          ></v-switch>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
      return {
        switch1: true,
      }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.my-border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the simply solution

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap it with `<v-card>` to achieve the effect.                    `<v-card flat class="pa-2" color="transparent"> </v-card>`